# Why does multiplying two first derivative finite difference matrices not give the matrix for the second derivative?

Tags: finite-difference

The finite difference matrix for the first derivative is

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

The finite difference matrix for the second derivative is

$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$.

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Why does multiplying together two first derivative matrices not give the second derivative matrix?

Comment: This is simply because $D_+ D_+ \neq D^2$ you need the information before and behind (to get the same stencil). Try multiplying $D_+ D_-$ (the forward diff operator and backward).

Comment: Thanks, however, I am wondering something like the following: $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$, so why does $D(Df) \neq D^2f$? You are taking the derivative of the derivative of $f$, so why do you not get the second derivative of $f$?

Comment: You do get D^2, just not the approximation you're thinking of. Try expanding these operators in a taylor series to see.

Comment: It would probably be better if you didn't think of your second matrix in the question as ***the*** FD matrix, but rather ***a*** FD matrix.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Just like there is a forward and a backward first derivative matrix, there are multiple choices to compute second derivatives. $D_+D_+$ happens to be one of them, just not the one you've seen before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the operators $$D_+^2 u = \frac{u_{n+2} - 2 u_{n+1} + u_n}{\Delta x^2}.$$
If you taylor expand this for small $\Delta x$ you arrive at
$$D_+^2 u = u_{xx} - \Delta x u_{xxx} + O(\Delta x^2)$$.
Thus $D_+^2 = D^2$ in the limit as $\Delta x \to 0$ (as it should), but note the error is first order in $\Delta x$ and so it is not a great approximation.

Consider instead, the one you are thinking of
$$D_- D_+ u = \frac{u_{n+1} - 2 u_n + u_{n-1}}{\Delta x^2}.$$
Again taking a taylor expansion we have
$$D_- D_+ u = u_{xx} + \frac{\Delta x^2}{12} u_{xxxx} + O(\Delta x^4).$$
Thus this approximation is actually better since the error goes down quadratically rather than linearly.

**However** in the limit they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrices are not well defined. The second derivative operator for example, takes three consecutive data values and outputs one second derivative value. That is not expressed by writing a square matrix.

There is a well-recognised Calculus of Finite Differences. You can find books with that phrase in the title, and you will find everything to be consistent and useful

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain??